# Google (Timer / Stopwatch) | Controls | parameters to start timer upon search

Tags: google-search

Let's just say you're getting tired and you decided to boil water at midnight. You decided to take a short nap...but little did you know that nap would've cost you your life. A simple question to ask yourself is "*should I have set a timer?*"

Sure, you could've, but how long does it take for one person to set a timer on their phone? For all I know is, it isn't efficient enough and in-fact a struggle to set timers on phones.

So what else am I always on besides my phone? Well, that's my PC of course.
Then I went to look for timers and found out about Google's very own search-term-specific one.

Google has a *timer-function*. It can be used by simply searching (w/ Google):

- the default is 5-mins

> timer

Now, the only thing missing is a way to set a specific time with the option to begin that timer immediately.

[image: screen shot]

## QUESTION

**How do I use Google's Timer function to set a specific time with the option to begin timer immediately**?

---

## FUNCTION

- There should be a way to set a specific time and option to begin timer via *parameters*, like so:

  - `command` + `time-in-no.'s` + `.`

> timer 30 min
>
> timer 55 sec.
>
> timer 1 hour and 22 min

## ALTERNATIVE

- Instead of using Google's timer you can use `duckduckgo` with the same parameters and it works entirely within your favor.

  - hours work
  - <del>combination of `time-formats` work</del> doesn't work
  - abbreviations work
  - alarm sounds less frightning
- for the most part, it's the clear winner

---

#### NOTE

- setting a timer w/ a keyboard is much more **quicker, effecient, & reliable**.

  - my hands on a keyboard obliterates me with my mouth next to a mic or my fingers on a phone.
  - I'm constantly on a browser.
- parameters should also work with all sorts of abbreviations

  - *minutes vs. min / mins*
  - *seconds vs. sec / secs*
- `.` parameter means begin timer
- search `stopwatch` for Google's other *timer-function* (*but, no parameters for this one and setting a time will default you to `timer`*).

Comment: What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: A way to use Google's timer function when you use their search engine to A) Set a time & B) to start that timer upon the search. I have a strong belief it can only be done via parameters.

Comment: Indeed. What, exactly, are you asking?

Comment: Besides, it's easy as pie to set a timer on my phone: I just need to say, out loud,  "OK, Google, set a timer for five minutes".

Comment: @AlE. The availability of phones is not universal; the question is about the desktop browser interface of Google search.

Comment: @sandwich: Which is why I just left a comment. Besides, the Asker starts out complaining how difficult it is to set a timer on a phone; I was merely offering a different view.

Comment: @AIE.: Or let's just say my phone is in my pocket but my hands are already on a keyboard. I would very much rather prefer to go at a browser to type out a timer rather than 1) getting my phone out, 2) unlocking my phone, 3) going to timer, 4) setting a time, hopefully without making a mistake. The time difference is incomparable. PC way is just **much** more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question right, you could simply type in x minute/second timer. It will then begin itself.

Comment: using `hour` doesn't work. only `minute` & `second`, BUT it can only be one **time-format** per search for timer to work.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking about my default search engine, duckduckgo, where hours, and combinations of times works, along with abbreviations.

Comment: THANK YOU! DDG is the obvious clear winner here. It does everything I've requested it do and operates in a fashion I like. Now I know what to use.

Comment: I'm glad I could introduce you to DDG, if not in a slightly roundabout way.

Answer (score 2):

> ## [1h2m3s timer](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=1h2m3s+timer)

works by now: [https://www.google.com/search?**hl=en**&q=1h2m3s+timer](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=1h2m3s+timer)

**Note!  This depends on the Google interface language being English** for the time being, unfortunately.  The parameter *hl=en* in the URL sets this.

If you only need 1 of a single unit°, you can leave out the digit, but then have to supply at least the 3-letter-abbreviation of the unit:

> [hour timer](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=hour+timer)
>      [min timer](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=min+timer)
>      [sec timer](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=sec+timer)

° E.g. 1 minute; but not 1 minute and 1 second.

---

You can use single values:

> [1m timer](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=2m+timer)

…and spaces:

> [1 h2m 3 s timer](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=1+h2m+3+s+timer)

You can put the `timer` keyword first:

> [timer 1h2m3s](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=timer+1h2m3s)

<sub>(Leading zeroes are allowed:</sub>

> <sub>[timer 01h2m 007 s](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=timer+01h2m+007+s)</sub>

<sub>)</sub>

---

<sub>Thanks [@Rubén](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%c3%a9n), who found the dependence on the English interface language!</sub>

Comment: This isn't working for me. So, I went ahead and clicked on your link to verify and it still defaults the timer to 5-min. Not only that, but the timer doesn't begin on it's own too :(

Comment: @fohrums, weird!  (So it behaves like for just the query `timer` without specifying a time (like `1h2m3s`).)  What exactly is the URL that misbehaves for you?  Please copy it from your address bar (<Ctrl>+<L> <Ctrl>+<C>) after you have loaded the search page.

Comment: Strange indeed, because not only did I click on your link provided (*every single one*) but did it not also work on another browser like Chrome. This is because i'm on Firefox. So, basically it just doesn't work and Google's timer function will always default to a 5m prompt for you to begin it yourself manually. **The problem is** having to manually begin it aswell as the incorrect time being prompted for the user to begin that timer.

Comment: I think that the problem is the default language. Add hl=en to the URL. Example: https://www.google.com.mx/search?hl=en&q=1h2m3s+timer

Comment: @Rubén, that seems to be it, thanks!  I updated my answer accordingly.  By the way, to add to the weirdness, even the *German* word "Stoppuhr" is recognized (as stopwatch), but *only* with the *English* interface: [google.com **.mx** /search? **hl=en** &q= **Stoppuhr**](https://www.google.com.mx/search?hl=en&q=Stoppuhr) works, [google **.de** /search?q= **Stoppuhr**](https://www.google.de/search?q=Stoppuhr) doesn't.

Comment: @fohrums, do the updated URLs from my answer work for you now?  Otherwise (as I said), please paste any faulty URL *from your address bar* – that's because Google typically alters the URL and that might possibly provide a hint at what's going wrong.

Comment: Even w/ the updated link to input the language it still dosen't work. I even tested the link using Internet Explorer, but proves unsuccessful. I even decided to try the same updated link using a proxy and that still didn't help :(

Answer (score 1):

## SOLUTION (*quick fix as google's own timer doesn't work as expected*)

### USING DUCKDUCKGO

- Quick

  - 2h30m05s timer
- Formal

  - 2 hour 30 min 05 sec timer

### <strike>USING GOOGLE</strike>

With Google's Timer, you can *set a specific time* & have *the time start automatically* upon search with the following syntax:

- `time-in-no.'s` + `time-format` + `timer`

> 30 second timer
>
> 999 minute timer

---

#### NOTE

- For the `time-formats` don't add an (s) or abbreviate it, for example:

  - `30 minutes timer`
  - `30 min timer`
  - only `30 minute timer` will work
- Only **seconds** & **minutes** work NOT **hours**

  - `27 second timer`
  - `40 minute timer`
  - <del>`1 hour timer`</del> (does not work)
  - so extend timer further by increasing the *minute* instead.
- Max minute allowed to set is equivalent to 1-day worth in hours

  - `1439 minute timer`

#### SUGGESTION

- It's much easier to work with abbreviated `time-formats`, so why not just implement that? Also, depending on people's way of wording things it'll be more universal by implementing abbreviated `time-formats`

  - e.g., abbreviated `time-formats` include:
  - minute = m / min / mins
  - hour = h / hr / hrs
  - second = s / sec / secs

Answer (score 0):

> ### search for [5h2m9sec timer](https://www.google.com/search?q=5h2m9sec+timer)

It works and it starts automatically!

- `timer` + `1h1m1sec`
- `1h1m1sec` + `timer`
- and other simpler ways